# How to get Top 10 values in Excel?

Tags: excel, data-analysis

[image: For data set click here]

In my dataset I have movie names, directors, imdb_score etc..so I have to get the top 10 directors whose imdb score highest. as the single director had directed multiple movies we have to calculate the mean of the imdb scores and then get the top 10 directors.

I have used the subtotal function to group the directors name and calculated their mean of imdb score in excel.

But i cant able to get the top 10 directors . please tell me how to get the top 10 directors whose mean of imdb score is larger.

Comment: It's more likely that you get an answer, if you provide some sample data and show us what you already have. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question.

Comment: I have added the link of the data set image could u check it out

Answer (score 0):

For your case let's say the data was different and all the columns you cared about were in columns A through C. Let's also say that you wanted the top ten of column B. In that case the formula is:

`=FILTER(A:C,B:B>LARGE(B:B,10))`